# How to save form/textarea to file with no file extension PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to pull a file in a textarea, edit it, then save the edited data to the same file. The submit function seems to go off, it posts the data, and in javascript console it returns the message "couldn't write values to file!", and in the original text area where it pulled the text from, it blanks out that file as if it overwrote the file with no information.

Am I using the wrong ID for my $data? (Textarea ID is edit, am presuming the information is coming from there).

I've used this same save setup on other .html pages, and am wondering if it is because I am saving to a file that has no file extension. If that is the issue, is there a way around that?

Maybe there is an issue elsewhere?

Snippet from my HTML page of the form area:

```
<form name="editorarea" method="post" action="/my/site/address/here/revotestingpdsave.php">
<textarea id="edit" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;">
<?php 
$filevar = "/my/site/address/here/revotesting/actions";
$handle = fopen($filevar, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filevar));
fclose($handle);

echo $contents;
?>
</textarea><p><input class="Save Button" type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" id="submit"></form></p></center>
```

And this is My Save Form PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$data = $_POST['edit'];
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
$data = stripslashes($data);}
$filevar = "/my/site/address/here/actions";

$fp = fopen($filevar, "w") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
echo "Saved to $filevar successfully!";

}
?>
<?php
// If this file is not on the server touch() will create it for you
$target = "/my/site/address/here/revotesting.cfg"; 
touch($target);
?>
```

Comment: Can you give the file 777 permission and try again? just to make sure it's not a permission problem.

Comment: I gave the file permissions 777 and still did the same thing. Returned the error could not write values to file and then blanked the textarea again on refresh as if it overwrote the file blankly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['edit']` is being sent empty, then it's being written to the file making it empty, just add `name` attribute to the textarea, like this:

```
<textarea id="edit" name="edit" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;">
```

Comment: Thank you Krane, completely missed that, however on adding the name attribute its still doing the same thing. Cleared cache and still chmodded to 777.

Comment: apologies, I apparantly am tired and forgot to save the edit to the server. It now saves successfully. Is there a way to have it not move to another page that shows the echo and instead stay on the same page after the successful save?

Comment: No worries, yes you can, just copy the `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` part and place it under the textarea in a PHP tag.

Comment: Thank you Krane, I added that beneath the text area.
<? if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

Comment: not sure what happened with my edit there had added that and it still redirected.

Comment: Yeah I meant move the whole second part to the first page, and remove the `action` attribute from the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

to display the successful message on the same page just move the revotestingpdsave.php content to the same page so

```
<form method="post">
// rest of form
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['edit'])) {
// add revotestingpdsave.php content here
}
?>
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it, putting my echo message at the bottom. Thank you Cygnus. The only issue is the change that gets saved doesn't show up until refresh (which is not a big deal) but the saved message (even on refresh to show the new content) stays on the page indefinitely which won't be too huge of an issue if they make multiple changes in a row, though showing the refreshed content on successful save would be nice. Also, is there a way to show where the echo message appears on success or to have it a popup? Thank you btw for the help!

Comment: you could use javascript, so instead of using PHP to echo a successful message you could echo a javascript alert then refresh the page.
e.g. 
`echo "<script>
if(!alert('saved')){window.location.reload();}
</script>";`