# How do I save form data to a text file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I know this question has been asked before, but I'm trying to diagnose why this isn't working. I want to write form data into a .txt file using a post request. I don't know much PHP at all, as this is a quick program I'm patching together. Here's the code:
Javascript:

```
function submitdata() {
document.querySelector("#val").innerHTML = input.value + ": " + input1.value;
document.querySelector("#submitform").submit(); }
```

HTML:

```
<form style="display: none;" method="POST" name="myform" id="submitform">
  <input id="val" name="val">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php           
if(isset($_POST['val']))
{
$data=$_POST['val'];
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save form/textarea to file with no file extension PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516053/how-to-save-form-textarea-to-file-with-no-file-extension-php)

Comment: It has a name associated with the element, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your browser know where to send the form data?
You need to specify the php file name in form action attribute.

Edit- added relevant point from comment below.

I have pointed out the obvious error based on what you have provided, but it might not be the only one. Other error is you are using innerHTML on an input element. So this may not set the value for #val (some browsers may set the value, some may not).

Comment: Even after specifying action="\testphp.php" it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are using a window style back slash ‘\’ in action. URLs use forward slash ‘/‘. Moreover if the php file and html are in the same directory, you don’t need any slash. Just use action=‘test.php’

Comment: I have pointed out the obvious error based on what you have provided, but it might not be the only one. Other error is you are using innerHTML on an input element. So this may not set the value for #val (some browsers may set the value, some may not). Also we do not know what is represented by input.value or input1.value. 

Have you checked the console of your browser? Is there any error / warning reported there?

Comment: Yup. That was the issue, changing .innerHTML to .value. Thanks a ton.